# Footer is scrollable horizontally but it shouldn't

Tags: html, css, footer

I created my site and the footer of it is scrollable horizontally but it shouldn't. It's wider than the rest of website.

HTML of footer:

```
<div class="footer">Atomdev.tk &copy; 2017</div>
```

CSS of footer:

```
.footer {
    width:100%;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    left: 0
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #222222;
    padding: 30px;
}
```

Here is my website with this footer: atomdev.tk

Comment: try to add `box-sizing: border-box;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either...

- add `box-sizing: border-box;` to `.footer` (by default the box model will add any `padding`s and `border`s to the calculated width of the element - `box-sizing: border-box` keeps the width of `padding`/`border` within the specified width)

or

- remove `width`(s) and add `right: 0;`

Comment: That worked! But now I noticed a tiny space between the footer and the browser bottom. If I add   border: 0;   to it, it sticks to the bottom of browser.